# Cannot add a new table to existing view using SSMS - SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am connecting to SQL Azure directly from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Once I have created my initial view, the option to Add Table by right clicking becomes greyed out. How can I solve this please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transact-SQL on SSMS to modify the View and add more tables.

```
ALTER VIEW HumanResources.EmployeeHireDate  
AS  
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, e.HireDate  
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e JOIN Person.Person AS p  
ON e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID  
WHERE HireDate < CONVERT(DATETIME,'20020101',101) ;  
GO
```

Comment: Thank you Alberto. The problem is that I'm an Access developer, so I plan and find errors in queries visually. T-SQL fries my brain after more than one join. Now I can also duplicate my Azure database in SQL Sever, create and edit my views there and script them back to Azure, but I was hoping for a direct solution.

Comment: When you start migrating to Azure SQL Database your Access databases, let me know to share with you a few good forum threads

Comment: Kind of you thanks.  The TSQL course will be useful please. The SQL Server Migration Assistant seemed to do the trick with Access.

Comment: I took this course myself. I hope you liked too. https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DAT201x+6T2016/course/